# Office 365 Calendar API retrieving only 10 records

Tags: calendar, office365, outlook-restapi

I am getting an Issue when trying to fetch the events from Office 365 Calendar
The issue is that I am able to fetch only 10 Events and eventsResult.MorePagesAvailable is always false

I have more than 50 meetings in a month and the eventsResult is fetching only 10

Code to fetch Events :-

```
 var eventSource = service.Me.Calendar.Events;

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(calendarId))
                {
  eventSource = service.Me.Calendars[calendarId].GetCalendarView(lowerBounday, upperBoundary);
   // lowerBounday - Start Date for fetching events from calendar
   // upperBoundary - End Date for fetching events from calendar

  var eventsResult = await (from i in eventSource orderby i.Start select i).ExecuteAsync();
 }
```

Same issue is coming for fetching all Calendars
I have more the 10 calendars in Office 365 but still getting only 10 with MorePagesAvailable as false.
Code to fetch All Calendars :-

```
 var allCalendars = await service.Me.Calendars.ExecuteAsync();
 bool checkNextPage = false;
                do
 {
  if (checkNextPage && allCalendars.MorePagesAvailable)
  {
   allCalendars = await allCalendars.GetNextPageAsync();
  }
  foreach (ICalendar calendar in allCalendars.CurrentPage)
  {
   lock (calendars)
   {
    calendars.Add(new CalendarData(calendar.Name, calendar.Id)
    {
     HasWriteAccess = true,
     IsFreeBusy = true
    });
   }
  }
  if(!checkNextPage)
   checkNextPage = true;
 } while(allCalendars.MorePagesAvailable)
```

We are using Microsoft.Office365 DLL's version 1.0.35 for this code.
It was working fine till 10-sept-2015. Is there anything changed with API or we are missing something?
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, looks like there's no `@odata.nextLink` being returned in the response. Let me see what I can find out.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a know issue that our engineers are working on. Sorry for the inconvenience!

UPDATE: The fix is in the pipeline. I'm seeing the `@odata.nextLink` in responses on my tenants, so it looks like it's hitting servers in production.

Answer (score -1):

10 is the default number. You need to use somthing like this https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0/me/messages?$top=number number= 5, 10...how many events you want. More details:https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersPageresults